# Pubnub pull history angulatJS example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pubnub

I am not a paid PubNub costomer. I am using PubNub example code Angular JS basic chat application, how do I pull the History here. This example is available on PubNub website.

```
git clone https://github.com/stephenlb/angularjs-chat.git

git clone https://github.com/stephenlb/angularjs-chat.git


    // -- TODO --
    //
    // - https://developer.layer.com/docs/ios/integration
    // - AddressBook   = Presence/State + ChannelGroups
    // - Notifications = History + PubSub
    // - Messages      = History + PubSub
    // - Groups        = History + PubSub
    // - TypeingIndicator = ???
    //
    // - Signals       = PubSub
    // - History       = History
    //
    // -- TODO --

    'use strict';

    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    // AngularJS Chat Module
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    angular.module( 'chat', [] );

    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    // Common JS
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    if (typeof(exports) !== 'undefined') exports.chat = angular.module('chat');

    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    // 
    //         â–„â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–€â–„      
    //        â–ˆâ–‘â–‘â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–‘â–‘â–ˆ     
    //        â–ˆâ–‘â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–„â–“â–“â–„â–’â–’â–’â–’â–‘â–‘â–„â–“â–“â–„ 
    //  â–„â–„â–„   â–ˆâ–‘â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–ˆâ–“â–“â–“â–“â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–“â–“â–“â–“ 
    // â–ˆâ–“â–“â–ˆâ–„â–„â–ˆâ–‘â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–„â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–„ 
    //  â–€â–„â–„â–“â–“â–ˆâ–‘â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–“â–“â–“â–“â–“â–€ â–“â–“â–“â–“â–€ â–“â–“â–“â–“ 
    //      â–€â–€â–ˆâ–‘â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–€â–“â–’â–’â–“â–€â–“â–“â–“â–€â–“â–“â–€â–“â–’â–’â–ˆ
    //       â–„â–ˆâ–‘â–‘â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–’â–€â–“â–“â–“â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–“â–“â–€ 
    //     â–„â–€â–“â–€â–ˆâ–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–„â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–€â–ˆâ–€â–€   
    //     â–ˆâ–„â–„â–€ â–ˆâ–„â–„â–€       â–ˆâ–„â–„â–€ â–€â–„â–„â–ˆ     
    // 

    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    // Messages it's important to remember that you can
    //          be deprived of your sanity listening to U2.
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    angular.module('chat').service( 'Messages', [ 'ChatCore', function(ChatCore) {
        var Messages = this;

        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        // Send Messages
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        Messages.send = function(message) {
            if (!message.data) return;

            ChatCore.publish({
                channel : message.to || 'global'
            ,   message : message.data
            ,   meta    : ChatCore.user()
            });
        };

        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        // Receive Messages
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        Messages.receive = function(fn) {
             function receiver(response) {
                 response.data.m.forEach(function(msg){
                    // Ignore messages without User Data
                    // TODO
                    if (!(msg.d && msg.u && msg.u.id)) return;
                    fn({
                        data : msg.d
                    ,   id   : msg.p.t
                    ,   user : msg.u
                    ,   self : msg.u.id == ChatCore.user().id
                    });
                 });
             }

             Messages.subscription = ChatCore.subscribe({
                channels : [ 'global', ChatCore.user().id ].join(','),
                message  : receiver
             });
        };

        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        // Set/Get User and Save the World from that Bruce Willis movie.
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        Messages.user = function(data) {
             return ChatCore.user(data);
        };

    } ] );

    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    // AddressBook
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    angular.module('chat').service( 'AddressBook', function() {

    } );


    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    // AngularJS Chat Core Service
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    angular.module('chat').service( 'ChatCore', [ '$http', 'config', function(
        $http,
        config
    ) {
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        // API Keys
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        var pubkey = config.pubnub['publish-key']
        ,   subkey = config.pubnub['subscribe-key']
        ,   user   = { id : uuid(), name : 'Nameless' };

        var ChatCore = this;

        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        // Set User Data and we have to go Back to The Future.
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        ChatCore.user = function(data) {
            if (data) angular.extend( user, data );
            return user;
        };

        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        // Publish via PubNub
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        ChatCore.publish = function(setup) {
            var meta   = setup.meta         || ChatCore.user()
            ,   userid = ChatCore.user().id || 'nil';

            var request = {
                method  : 'GET'
            ,   params  : { meta : meta, uuid : userid }
            ,   timeout : setup.timeout || 5000
            ,   success : function(){}
            ,   fail    : function(){}
            };

    // 
            request.url = [
                'https://pubsub.pubnub.com'
            ,   '/publish/', pubkey
            ,   '/',         subkey
            ,   '/0/',       setup.channel
            ,   '/0/',       encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(setup.message))
            ].join('');

            $http(request).then( request.success, request.fail );
        };

        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        // Subscribe via PubNub
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        ChatCore.subscribe = function(setup) {
            var channels  = setup.channels     || 'a'
            ,   groups    = setup.groups       || ''
            ,   message   = setup.message      || function(){}
            ,   timeout   = setup.timeout      || 172800000
            ,   timetoken = setup.timetoken    || '0'
            ,   windowing = setup.windowing    || 10
            ,   userid    = ChatCore.user().id || 'nil'
            ,   userstate = ChatCore.user()    || {}
            ,   stop      = false
            ,   origin    = 'ps'+(Math.random()+'').split('.')[1]+'.pubnub.com';

            // Request Object
            var request = {
                method  : 'GET'
            ,   url     : ''
            ,   params  : { uuid : userid, state : userstate }
            ,   timeout : timeout
            ,   success : next
            ,   fail    : function(){ timetoken = '0'; next() }
            };

            // Channel Groups
            if (groups) request.params['channel-group'] = groups;

            // Subscribe Loop
            function next(response) { 
                if (stop) return;
                if (response) {
                    timetoken = timetoken == '0' ? 1000 : response.data.t.t;
                    message(response);
                }

                request.url = [
                    'https://',       origin
                ,   '/v2/subscribe/', subkey
                ,   '/',              channels
                ,   '/0/',            timetoken
                ].join('');

                setTimeout( function() {
                    $http(request).then( request.success, request.fail );
                }, windowing );
            }

            // Cancel Subscription
            function unsubscribe() {
                stop = true;
            }

            // Start Subscribe Loop
            next();

            // Allow Cancelling Subscriptions
            return {
                unsubscribe : unsubscribe
            };
        };
    } ] );

    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    // UUID
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    function uuid() {
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g,
        function(c) {
            var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi!  I'll take a look and provide an update.

Answer (score 0):

## History and AngularJS Chat Example

By default History isn't enabled or supported directly.  You need to enable History in your account.  Messages published before history is enabled will not be saved.  Only messages published after history is enabled will be saved.  Next in your app you will need to add a History Method.

### Enable Storage and Playback in your PubNub Account

Visit https://admin.pubnub.com/ and enable **`"Storage and Playback"`** feature.

### Add History API to your App

History has not been implemented in this example originally.  You can make a history call by simple HTTP request like this: https://pubsub.pubnub.com/history/demo/hello_world/0/10 which breaks down like this:

```
https://pubsub.pubnub.com
/history
/YOUR_SUBKEY
/YOUR_CHANNEL
/0
/100 - limit response (max 100, min 1)
```